# VBA script to export sheets as CSV files to a specific location after deleting rows that are blank or "blank" but contain formula

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-csv, savefiledialog

I am working on a VBA script to allow manipulation and export of a number of worksheets as csv files from an Excel workbook. I'd like to be able to export a list of specified sheets as csv files to a save location that is able to be selected, in addition any cell in a specific column that is blank but may contain a formula needs to be have the entire row deleted. The below script is what I currently have and it seems to work to a point but there are three main issues:

1. The line below will remove lines if the cell in column A is really blank i.e contains no formula, but does not work if formula is present:                  `Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete`
2. The cycling through the sheets is untidy but functional, is there a way to use a list of named sheets to make the script more concise?
3. Ideally the save location would also be selectable from a choose file directory dialog box. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance.

```
Sub createCSVfiles()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Declare and set variables
Dim wb1 As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet
Dim wbname As String, i As Integer
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

'Cycle through sheets
For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    wbname = Worksheets(i).Name

'Create Sheet1.csv
  If InStr(1, (Worksheets(i).Name), "Sheet1", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
       Worksheets(i).Copy
       Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
       ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\forename.surname\Desktop\export\" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".csv", _
       FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close
      wb1.Activate
End If

'Create Sheet2.csv
If InStr(1, (Worksheets(i).Name), "Sheet2", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    Worksheets(i).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\forename.surname\Desktop\export\" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".csv", _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    wb.Activate
End If

Next i

'Clean
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What I don't understand is that you copy a _Worksheet_ and then later close the _Workbook_.  Now there is no workbook anymore to work with and the macro will stop: your Sheet2 part will not run. And you say it works?

Comment: I also notice that (even if it would run) that after the copy, you have another worksheet in your workbook named "Sheet x (2)" and you don't delete that sheet (you save it, but that doesn't remove it). Now `Worksheets.Count` is incremented so you loop at least once more. The new sheet matches your `InStr` criterium and so the process repeats again and again. It repeats infinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this is what you're looking for:

```
Sub createCSVfiles()

    'Declare and set variables
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim aSheets() As Variant
    Dim vSheet As Variant
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim sNewFileName As String
    Dim oShell As Object
    Dim i As Long

    'Select folder to save CSV files to
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    On Error Resume Next
    sFilePath = oShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select folder to save csv files", 0).Self.Path & Application.PathSeparator
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Len(sFilePath) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'Pressed cancel

    'Define sheet names here
    aSheets = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    'Cycle through sheets
    For Each vSheet In aSheets
        'Test if sheet exists
        Set ws = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(vSheet)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
            'Sheet exists
            ws.Copy
            Set wsTemp = ActiveSheet

            'Remove rows with blanks in column A
            With wsTemp.Range("A1", wsTemp.Cells(wsTemp.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
                .AutoFilter 1, "=", xlFilterValues
                .Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
                .AutoFilter
            End With

            'Save and close
            wsTemp.Parent.SaveAs sFilePath & wsTemp.Name & ".csv", xlCSV
            wsTemp.Parent.Close False
        End If
    Next vSheet

    'Clean
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

End Sub
```